# Google Analytics API Embed Not Populating Data

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I am working with the Google Analytics API for Javascript embeds. I am working on a local server (XAMPP). I can authenticate, or login to the service. However, none of the div content (or actual data) populates. I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong. I will attach the code below. Please note that the "//My-GA-ID//" has been replaced for the supplied code. I do have a functional ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(w, d, s, g, js, fs){
            g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
            g.analytics = {
                q: [],
                ready: function(f){
                    this.q.push(f);
                }
            };
            js = d.createElement(s);
            fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
            js.onload = function(){
                g.load('analytics');
            };
        }(window, document, 'script'));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        gapi.analytics.ready(function(){

            /**
             * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
             * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
             * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
             */
            gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
                clientid: '//MY-GA-ID//'
            });

            /**
             * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
             * element with the id "view-selector-container".
             */
            var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
                container: 'view-selector-container'
            });

            // Render the view selector to the page.
            viewSelector.execute();

            /**
             * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
             * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
             * with the id "chart-container".
             */
            var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                    metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                    dimensions: 'ga:date',
                    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                    'end-date': 'yesterday'
                },
                chart: {
                    container: 'chart-container',
                    type: 'LINE',
                    options: {
                        width: '100%'
                    }
                }
            });

            /**
             * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
             */
            viewSelector.on('change', function(ids){
                dataChart.set({
                    query: {
                        ids: ids
                    }
                }).execute();
            });

        });
    </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
        Here is the auth:
        <div id="embed-api-auth-container">
        </div>
        <br>
        Here is the chart
        <div id="chart-container">
        </div>
        <br>
        Here is the View
        <div id="view-selector-container" style="width: 400px; height: 300;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "//MY-GA-ID// " You are giving it a client id right not the property from google analytics?

Comment: That is correct. For example, "a bunch of numbers..apps.googleusercontent.com"

I can get past authorization. It will tell me that I am successfully logged in. However, the data does not populate afterward.

Comment: If it helps, I also notice the following information in the console.

cb=gapi.loaded_0:88 GET https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?max-results=0&_src=embed-api%3Av1 403 ()

{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Example in the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started). You need to wait to execute the `viewSelector` for after you authorize the application. Replace the line `viewSelector.execute();`

with:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });
```

And things should work out a little bit better.

#### Note: You must have an account you actually own for the API to work. Querying for data against the "Demo Account (Beta)" will fail.

Comment: I made the edits and it's still not displaying any data itself. I even copy/pasted the sample that you linked. Same situation. I can successfully log in, but no data. Any thoughts?

Comment: Still noticing the following error when I inspect: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when you [use the example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started). If you use the correct client ID with the appropriate origin `localhost:8080` set in the dev console, and you are logging in to an account which actually has an Analytics account.

Comment: If I launch the browser, I am greeted with an "Access Google Analytics" button. I can login, and receive the message "login successful: email@domain.com"

However, nothing else happens with the divs. No data is shown. If I inspect the element with browser tools, I can see the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

If I expand that error, it reads:
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}

Comment: Are you selecting the account "Demo Account (Beta)"? The API does not work with the Demo account you need to select one of your own accounts. Try selecting one the accounts you own.

Comment: That's the thing. I cannot 'select' anything. I simply log in and then I am greeted with "login successful: email@domain.com." Nothing else is shown on the page whatsoever. Does that help to clarify? Really appreciate the help, Matt.

Comment: I am (to my knowledge) querying from my account. I supply my credentials and have activated the api with my client ID.

Comment: You should see a few more things on your page: "Here is the chart

Here is the View
Account  <ACCOUNT SELECTOR>
Property  <PROPERTY SELECTOR>
View  <VIEW SELECTOR>
"
Even if you do not have a Google Analytics account these things should show up.

Comment: It should be a very similar experience if you go to the [demos and tools](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) site.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I can see my headings before the divs. So I can see :

New Web Project Page
Here is the auth:
Here is the chart:
Here is the View:

I do not see anything else. No data populates.

Comment: Are there drop down menus next to the headings? are those menus populated with accounts, properties and views? does the same thing happen in a different browser with no ad blocking extensions. What happens when you go into the console and type `gapi.client.analytics.management.accountSummaries.list()`

Comment: I do not have access to any dropdown menus, so they are not populated with accounts, properties or views. I have tried multiple browsers with all adblockers removed/paused. If I supply your command to console it reads, "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined()"

Comment: Do you have an Analytics account? What happens if you go to [Google Analytics Website](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web)? does it prompt you to `Start analyzing your site's traffic in 3 steps`? I would also try killing the XAMPP server and see what happens if you serve it from a simple Python server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Comment: I do have an analytics account with several properties. I have tried multiple accounts without success. It simply doesn't display a dropdown menu. I'm unfamiliar with simple Python server configuration, but I can look into it.